# Option in select with span text

Tags: javascript, jquery

External system generates translations and replace literals with span text on the page. It works perfectly fine for the most of places but it doesn't work with options in select. They support only text. As the result my page has the issue like here [**SQL Fiddle sample**](https://jsfiddle.net/xyp8L8c6/2/).

```
<select class="ProductInfo" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt1&lt;/span&gt;</option>
    <option value="1">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt2&lt;/span&gt;</option>
</select>
```

I want some jquery/javascript function that would replace option content with just text and remove wrapper in above.

Expected result:

```
<select class="ProductInfo" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">Opt1</option>
    <option value="1">Opt2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to fix in the template itself, if that is not possible you can try something like

```js
$('.ProductNoInfo option').text(function(i, t) {
  return $(t).text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ProductNoInfo">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt1&lt;/span&gt;</option>
  <option value="1">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt2&lt;/span&gt;</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `decodeURICompoenent`

```js
$("select option").each(function() {
  this.textContent = $(decodeURIComponent(this.textContent)).text()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ProductInfo" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt1&lt;/span&gt;</option>
    <option value="1">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt2&lt;/span&gt;</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.ProductNoInfo option').each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).find('span').text());
});
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is your solution and how does it solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('.ProductInfo option').each(function () {
            this.textContent = $(decodeURIComponent(this.textContent)).text()
        });


        });  
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <select class="ProductInfo" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt1&lt;/span&gt;</option>
    <option value="1">&lt;span class='translation'&gt;Opt2&lt;/span&gt;</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```